# handle underscore in protobuf file scala

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, proto

I have written a proto file, something like this:

```
message MetaRun {
   required RedoIntent redo_intent = 1;
}
```

What proto is doing, it is making redo_intent to redoIntent. How to avoid doing this?

Comment: Are you using https://scalapb.github.io/ ?

Comment: also, https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html